# A conjecture of real quadratic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have calculated some Hilbert class fields of real quadratic field with class number $2$,and I found $Gal(H_{K}/Q)\cong Z/2Z\oplus Z/2Z$,here $H_{K}$ is the Hilbert class field of some real quadratic field whose class number is $2$.So I want to know whether this is true for all real quadratic field with class number $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is. Since Hilbert class fields of normal extensions are normal by maximality, $H_K$ is normal over the rationals. Since there are only two groups of order $4$, the Galois group is either cyclic or Klein's 4-group. If $H_K/{\mathbb Q}$ were cyclic, all primes ramifying in $K/{\mathbb Q}$ would also ramify in $H_K/K$ (since the inertia subfield, the maximal extension in which the prime is unramified, would have to be ${\mathbb Q}$: recall that $K$ is the unique quadratic subextension of $H_K$ in this case), but this extension is unramified. Since there are no unramified quadratic number fields, this proves the claim.

Comment: You say"If HK/Q were cyclic, all primes ramifying in K/Q would also ramify in HK/K",that not obvious,could you explain it more detailed?@franz lemmermeyer

Comment: This follows from Dedekind's and Hilbert's theory of splitting and inertia subfields - see the edit.